# How remove active date from a dynamic block using columnview

Tags: org-mode, org-table, time-date

[This post](https://egli.dev/posts/using-org-mode-for-meeting-minutes/) explains how you can setup [dynamic blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Dynamic-Blocks.html#Dynamic-Blocks) to create tables based on meeting minutes.

In short, you can extract the TODOs of the minutes and put them in a table of actions like so:

```
* Actions
#+BEGIN: columnview :id global :match "/TODO|DONE" :format "%ITEM(What) %TAGS(Who) %DEADLINE(When) %TODO(State)"
| What                     | Who          | When            | State |
|--------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-------|
| Inventory of equipment   | :@Fred:      |                 | TODO  |
| Definition of main goals | :@Sara:      |                 | TODO  |
| Talk to companies        | :@Lucy:@Ted: | <2020-03-01 So> | DONE  |
#+END:
```

This uses the `columnview` dynamic block to automatically generate and keep the table up-to-date.

It works well except for the date. It extracts the active date in the `<2020-03-01 So>` format. This causes the insertion of an empty duplicated entry in my agenda view for this date.

Is there a way to convert the date to inactive, so it is displayed as `[2020-03-01 So]` in the table?

Comment: Nice question! I am not at all sure that I'm reading the documentation correctly (I don't know much about column view), but [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) seems to indicate that `%DEADLINE` in the format should be the DEADLINE string *without* the angle brackets, persumably for exactly the reason you describe - yet it isn't. So not quite sure yet, but this might be a bug worth reporting to the mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @NickD for the tip. I posted to the mailing list and got a [solution](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2020-05/msg00183.html) from Kyle Meyer. They are keeping the behaviour above, that is, keeping the active dates to prevent breaking other parts of the code and third-party libraries. And they are updating the docs instead.

Then, in my case, to remove the angle brackets, the solution is to add the following to my init.el file:

```
(defun my/org-columns-remove-brackets (_title value)
      (and (string-match org-ts-regexp value)
           (match-string 1 value)))

(setq org-columns-modify-value-for-display-function
      #'my/org-columns-remove-brackets)
```

Comment: Actually, I think the current thinking is to change them to inactive dates, but the change has not made it into the code yet.

Comment: The change from active to inactive timestamps is now in [upstream master](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/7684b59c78cbd6d1deb92f94bb96fc18c1eeb95a).